# Array write to CSV

Tags: php

I have an array that I want to write to a CSV file and tried the fputcsv function following the example on the manual.

However I am getting the error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function fputcsv()"

```
$csv = array();
foreach($compare as $ukvalue)
{   
    $csv[] = array($ukvalue, $uk[$ukvalue]);
}



$fp = fopen("lang.csv", "w");

foreach ($csv as $fields) 
    {
        fputcsv($fp,explode(',', $fields));
    }

    fclose($fp);
```

Can anyone shed some light on this issue or is there an alternative to fputcsv I can try?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: fputcsv is available since PHP 5.1.0

Comment: @Wooble [official php documentation](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: `fputcsv`is available for PHP 5.1.0 and above, you should check your version using `phpinfo()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the docs at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php the function `putcsv` is available only for **PHP 5.1.0 or later**

Which version oh PHP are you running?

Also, you should **not** `explode` the fields, in fact the expected second parameter should be an `array`.

Comment: Sorry everyone I thought I was running 5.1 but it's 5.0.4 thanks for your responses!